# npm i bootstrap command not working for install boostrap

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angularjs

npm i bootstrap command not working for installing bootstrap. Nothing added to packages.json file and to node_modules.`

package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the error?

**You can try:-**

```
 1. Delete the node_modules folder
 2. npm cache clean --force
 3. npm i
 4. npm i bootstrap
```